# Add several properties to css will-change

Tags: css

I am using `will-change: transform` in my css to accelerate element animations, I was wondering if there is a way to add more than one property to this i.e. have transform and opacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) and [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change-1/) it is possible by using a comma:

```
.element {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

You might be already aware of this, but for the sake of completeness:

> **Don’t Spam will-change Across Too Many Properties or Elements**
>
> A common initial response to seeing will-change is to assume that code like this is a good idea:
>
> * { will-change: transform, opacity /* , ... */; }
>
> After all, this tells the browser to go ahead and optimize everything, which has to be good right?
>
> Wrong. The browser already tries as hard as it can to optimize everything. Telling it to do so explicitly doesn’t help anything, and in fact has the capacity to do a lot of harm; some of the stronger optimizations that are likely to be tied to will-change end up using a lot of a machine’s resources, and when overused like this can cause the page to slow down or even crash. [[W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change-1/)]